# PM2 + Meteor Environment Setup

Tags: meteor

I am trying to setup Meteor to use pm2 (https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) instead of forever as the node process monitor.  I have had no luck in getting the environment variables that a Meteor application needs to be seen by the pm2 process.

Here is my process:

```
export MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor"
export PORT=4000
export ROOT_URL="https://beta.example.com/"
pm2 start main.js --name MyMeteorApp
```

In the error log from pm2 I see that my Meteor application is complaining that it cannot find `MONGO_URL`.

Is there a specific way that I need to do the exports in order to work with pm2?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After doing some digging I found the right answer.  In pm2 anything that you place inside the JSON task definition that isn't one of the reserved keywords is exported to the process that you are running inside of pm2 as an environment variable.

Comment: such as what variable name?

Comment: Please provide an example of how your JSON file is when placing inside the tasks definition. Otherwise, I won't undo my negative evaluation for this answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can create `process.json` (PM2 fleet configuration file) file where you can specify environment variables.

For example:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "MyMeteorApp",
      "script": "./main.js",
      "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
      "exec_mode": "fork_mode",
      "env": {
        "PORT": 4000,
        "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor",
        "ROOT_URL": "https://beta.example.com/"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

for start: `pm2 start processes.json`

Comment: is there a way to add meteor --settings to this?

Comment: @JohhanSantana Yeah, insert an environment variable along the others like so:
`"METEOR_SETTINGS": {
          'private': { ... },
          'public': { ... }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

Go and checkout pm2-meteor. Should help you with generating a pm2-env.json.

```
$ npm i -g pm2-meteor
$ cd myMeteorProject
$ pm2-meteor --settings meteor-settings.json
```

Answer (score 2):

> **as of 2018**

I faced a big issue like this but now everthing is solved.

When you are using PM2 for your customised production of Meteor App, then you just place a file `process.json` inside `bundle` directory and run below command,

```
pm2 start process.json
```

Below are the parameters of file `process.json` that I wanted to pass as `METEOR_SETTINGS` in the production environment,

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "My APP",
      "script": "./main.js",
      "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
      "exec_mode": "fork_mode",
      "env": {
        "PORT": 3000,
        "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname",
        "ROOT_URL": "http://hostname/",
        "METEOR_SETTINGS": {
            "MAIL_URL": "smtps://<your username>:<your password>@smtp.gmail.com:465",
            "AUTHKEY": "185938A0asmD231231231231e4992",
            "HOSTNAME": "some example",
            "public": {
                "COMPANY_NAME": "Some Company Name"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, in above code you can see how I have set `METEOR_SETTINGS`.

Comment: Isn't possible to retrieve the settings from the root of your project file settings.json and load them up with PM2? Should be necessary to define the Meteor settings in the process.json?

Comment: @yajairo: You can try that as well as I have not.

Comment: hi @AnkurSoni - you need to fix your METEOR_SETTINGS - you've put in the section called public but forgotten to put the others in a section called private.  cheers

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit weird with pm2. But something like this can work

```
pm2 kill
MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor" PORT=4000 ROOT_URL="https://beta.example.com/" pm2 start app.js --name MyMeteorApp
```

It happens because pm2 wraps everything into a new process of its own which can't see the variables of the original environment. I think theres also a way to put environment variables in the JSON file but i'm not sure how exactly as the docs are a bit empty