# Deploy meteor app with git / repository?

Tags: node.js, git, meteor, meteor-up

I've been searching around the web to see what's the best/simplest way to deploy a meteor app, and have found that Meteor Up has been the easiest way to do this.

However, I've been noticing that this works pretty awesome on small apps, now that one of our apps has grown larger than 250mb, Meteor Up has to build and deploy the whole 250mb app again and again for even the smallest change.

With other node applications we have on digital ocean, a simple `git pull` does the trick without having to re-upload the entire application.

Is there a way to maintain a meteor application with a github/bitbucket repository?

Thanks!

Comment: the app is 250Mb because of content or because of code? Meteor compiles and minifies the code to generate the code behind the templates, so you can't just `git pull` a meteor app and not build. However, if you serve a lot of content, and that's what is taking up space/time to upload and build etc... then you should really consider using a cdn. Or if your static assets are served from a predefined folder, you could put those in their own repo and git pull that on your server.

Comment: I think you will find that the idea of uploading only the changed items is not possible at the moment, but I read somewhere that it's on the Meteor roadmap for the near future. Sorry if I can't at the moment find where I heard this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found a solution for this.

Reference: [PM2 + Meteor Environment Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522551/pm2-meteor-environment-setup)

Using `meteor build` and following the README that it generates, I was able to run the bundle without using meteor up.

This helps at deploying since it skips the process of uploading the entire bundle to the server, instead, just use git pull in the server to pull your code changes and use `meteor build` to create the build and run it with `pm2`.