# Steps to setup pm2 to monitor a meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor, cpu-usage, pm2

I am trying to use pm2 to monitor my meteor app, intending to resolve the issue of cpu 100% usage.

I refereed to [PM2 + Meteor Environment Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522551/pm2-meteor-environment-setup), but the result looked like a failure.

My idea is that the meteor process was not initiated at all. Any ideas are welcome.

[image]

By the way, I've tried pm2-meteor, but probably because it is not maintained, it now cannot run successfully.

[image]

My code structure is listed as such,

```
+- cloud
  +- package.json
  +- client
  +- server
  +- pm2.json
  +- private
  +- public
  +- server
```

In the normal mode, I run the web app by get to cloud folder and the 'meteor'instruction.

Comment: You need to init pm2-meteor on your local machine, not on your server. It uses a configuration file to build and deploy everything for you. See: https://github.com/andruschka/pm2-meteor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the cause of my issue is in [Nodejs always installing 4.2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583919/nodejs-always-installing-4-2-6)

So after update the nodejs on my machine, I need to make a decision to choose a way to run pm2

```
1. pm2-meteor in https://github.com/andruschka/pm2-meteor
2. run mongodb and it listens to 172.0.0.1:27010 
   + meteor build the app to be .tar.gz
   + pm2 run meteor app
```

I use 2. so the steps are,

```
1. install mongodb, pm2, nodejs(nodejs installation with nvm please)

2. In order to create a mongodb service
   - launch mongod by 
     mongod -dbpath=$(some_accessible_path) -logpath=$(some_accessible_path) --fork --replSet meteor

3. run mongo and get to mongo shell and key in commands bellow
   a. var config = {_id:"meteor",members:[{_id:0,host:"127.0.0.1:27017"}]}
   b. rs.initiate(config)
   if the return value is {"ok":1}, mongodb service is ready.

4. pack meteor app
   a. mkdir ~/cloud_build
   b. get to the source code folder and use the command
      meteor build --architecture=os.linux.x86_64 ~/cloud_build
   c. cd ~/cloud_build
   d. tar xvf some.tar.gz
   e. you will get a bundle folder
   f. cd that_bundle_folder/program/server && npm install

5. run pm2
   a. create a file of pm2.json in the bundle folder 
   b. pm2 start pm2.json
```

the pm2.json looks like something bellow

```
{
  "apps": [{
  "name": "appName",
  "cwd": "/yourhome/cloud_build/bundle",
  "script": "main.js",
  "env": {
  "NODE_ENV": "production",
  "WORKER_ID": "0",
  "PORT": "3000",
  "ROOT_URL": "http://yourweburl",
  "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor",
  "MONGO_OPLOG_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/local",
  "HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT": "1",
  "METEOR_SETTINGS": {}
  }
  }]
}
```

Then the webapp can be accessed in http://yourweburl:3000